# Storing sessions in Redis while being able to revoke all sessions of a user

Tags: session, redis, session-state

When a user authenticates on my website, either via email & password or OAuth (Google, Apple, Facebook...), I create a cookie with the session id of the user and store the session data in Redis.

The session data is the following (it gets serialised as a string):

```json
{
  "id": "random_session_id",
  "iat": 1677004020931,
  "userId": "id_of_the_user_who_owns_the_session",
  "device": "Samsung s10",
  "ip": 0.0.0.0,
}
```

And it's stored with the `id` as the Redis key and an expiration time, which is the same as the `maxAgeInSeconds` property of the cookie obviously.

My issue is that **I need to invalidate all the sessions of a user when he resets his password**.
To do that I thought of storing the sessions with hashes in Redis, like so:

```
 - user_id
   |--> session_id_1
        |--> session_data_serialised
   |--> session_id_2
        |--> another_session_data_serialised
 - user_id_2
   |--> session_id_3
        |--> session_data_serialised
   |--> session_id_4
        |--> session_data_serialised
```

The issue with this approach is that you cannot set an expiration on hashes in Redis, so this is not an option for me.

I then though of creating another cache where I put all the sessions of each user but then I also need to remove the entries from this cache when the session expires and it doesn't seem possible.

How should I achieve my goal here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can make it simpler redis structure.

Example scenario:

- User ID is `112233`
- User login in Mobile & Desktop, so it will be created 2 session.

It is the visualization of redis structure, this using Redis Strings

`112233:${mobile session id}`

`112233:${desktop session id}`

So how **to invalidate all the sessions of a user when he resets his password**? for example you cane use this command (or you can use search pattern to more safe)

`DEL 112233:*`

and the expiration of keys works well in this structure.

Comment: Tysm did not remember you could use `*` to match values in Redis ^^

Comment: Down side to this is that redis will scan the entire key space looking for sessions to clear which will block other operations. It doesn't scale.

Comment: What's the solution to that issue @TheCycoONE ?

Comment: Adding a separate set of userId -> sessionId which you move the expiry on when you touch any of the inner sessions. O(1), when you log in create the session key and add the key to this map O(1), when you change password, remove all sessions in the set (smembers or sscan). When you log out remove the session and the set.

It may be desirable to iterate over the set members on login/logout to remove any other stale sessions if you don't reliably get events for them to prevent a chain of abandoned sessions from growing the set. In any case you are never running KEYS or SCAN.